# octave version upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, octave

Is there a way to upgrade my octave version on Ubuntu without downloading the latest version and reinstalling from scratch? (my current version is 3.0.0 and I want the latest stable version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your ubuntu version? karmic?

Found octave 3.2 for karmic, though the latest version is 3.2.3

http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/octave3.2

Comment: Thanks, I updated to karmic and then ran:
sudo apt-get install octave3.2
it worked!